# SSMS invalid character in system.xml

Tags: ssms

When I try to connect to a database server from Sql Server Management Studio, I get the message:

```
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 249, position 83. (System.Xml)
```

I can't find any relevant file called system.xml. Any idea what folder this is in? Or any other clue how to fix this problem?

There are only 2 of us who manage this server. This was working last week and neither of us messed with SSMS or any sort of configuration.

This is on an Amazon Web Services server, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This has been happening to us for over a week, also AWS.